# How to get "SoftLayer_Product_PackageInitParameters" for Vyatta

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Trying to deploy Vyatta and it fails with the error:

```
"error": "The item price (id 33867) for '20000 GB Bandwidth Allotment' is not contained within the specified package (id 1055). Could not determine active upgrade price for \"20000 GB Bandwidth Allotment\". ",
"code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Order_Item_Unavailable"
```

I need to fetch the correct Price ID which is dependent of SoftLayer_Product_Package which can be obtained using a rest api

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItems/

The Rest API requires you to pass                                      "SoftLayer_Product_PackageInitParameters": a mandatory header and it does not point on how to get this information.

Is there a way to achieve more information on getting the PackageInitParameters as most of the attributes like for ex: getItemPrices depends on the PackageInitParameters

Thank you
Anish

Answer (score 0):

The **SoftLayer_Product_PackageInitParameters** is the ID of package. I see you are using the package 1055 then to retrieve the list of items try with the following:

`https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/1055/getItems`

To see the list of package and their IDs:

`https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects`

It is more easy with `slcli`, if you see below the package ids for gateways are 174, 196, 236, 1055, and 1057, the last two are currently used by the control portal.

```
$ slcli order package-list | grep GATEWAY
174   Network Gateway Appliance                                   NETWORK_GATEWAY_APPLIANCE                               BARE_METAL_GATEWAY                                  
196   Network Gateway Appliance Cluster                           NETWORK_GATEWAY_APPLIANCE_CLUSTER                       GATEWAY_RESOURCE_GROUP                              
236   Network Gateway Appliance (10 Gbps)                         2U_NETWORK_GATEWAY_APPLIANCE_1O_GBPS                    BARE_METAL_GATEWAY                                  
1055  Virtual Router Appliance                                    VIRTUAL_ROUTER_APPLIANCE_1_GPBS                         BARE_METAL_GATEWAY                                  
1057  Virtual Router Appliance (10 Gpbs)                          VIRTUAL_ROUTER_APPLIANCE_10_GPBS                        BARE_METAL_GATEWAY
```

Comment: slcli order package-list | grep GATEWAY
    Network Gateway Appliance                                               NETWORK_GATEWAY_APPLIANCE                               BARE_METAL_GATEWAY

I'm unable to find the "ID" in the output.

Do you think I'm missing anything in the setup. Without the ID I'm unable to complete the deploymmet

Comment: the ID values should be at the left of the response, try with `slcli order package-list`, it will return all packages in a pretty table. If you want to use REST then run `https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects`

Comment: make sure you are using the latest version of slcli (v5.6.4)

Answer (score 0):

The "slcli order place" uses the "keyName" of the items instead of "ids".

The control portal uses the following options to create a Vyatta Gateway:

- **Single Processor Multi-Core Servers**

  "keyName": VIRTUAL_ROUTER_APPLIANCE_1_GPBS

  "packageId" 1055
- **Dual Processor Multi-Core Servers**

  "keyName": VIRTUAL_ROUTER_APPLIANCE_10_GPBS

  "packageId": 1057

I suggest you to comparing with the control portal when you are creating your Vyatta Gateway.

Below there is an example, how to create a Vyatta by slcli.

```
slcli order place --verify --billing monthly VIRTUAL_ROUTER_APPLIANCE_1_GPBS AMSTERDAM INTEL_INTEL_XEON_E31270_V6_3_80 RAM_16_GB_DDR4_2133_ECC_NON_REG OS_VIRTUAL_ROUTER_APPLIANCE_18_X_UP_TO_1GBPS_SUBSCRIPTION_EDITION_64_BIT DISK_CONTROLLER_NONRAID HARD_DRIVE_2_00_TB_SATA_2 BANDWIDTH_5000_GB 1_GBPS_PUBLIC_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINKS MONITORING_HOST_PING AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION UNLIMITED_SSL_VPN_USERS_1_PPTP_VPN_USER_PER_ACCOUNT NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING 1_IP_ADDRESS NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_AND_TICKET REBOOT_KVM_OVER_IP SRIOV_ENABLED --extras '{"quantity":1,"hardware": [{"hostname":"test","domain":"softlayer.com"}]}' --complex-type SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server_Gateway_Appliance
```

I am using the "Single Processor Multi-Core Servers" with the

"keyName":"VIRTUAL_ROUTER_APPLIANCE_1_GPBS"

The "--verify" option is to check if all the items are correct, when you are ready, remove the "--verify" option to make your order.

With the below slcli command you can retrieve all the items available for this "PACKAGE_KEYNAME", VIRTUAL_ROUTER_APPLIANCE_1_GPBS.

```
slcli order item-list VIRTUAL_ROUTER_APPLIANCE_1_GPBS
```

Do not forget to use only the "keyName" options for your request.

Comment: Thank you. We would like this to be done using the Rest API Automation and it is getting quite cumbersome to do it. 

For ex: If we were to get the DataCenter using the Rest API......It only gives me the short name and not the Key

https://aaaa@info:c619b539ddda7fd8396418bnghyuioljyh@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Location_Datacenter/getDatacenters

The Output is in the below form

    {
        "id": 265592,
        "longName": "Amsterdam 1",
        "name": "ams01",
        "statusId": 2
    },

Now if we were to deploy we need the key which is in "AMSTERDAM"

Comment: We are stuck as it takes the Key and not the id's nor the shortnames

Comment: With this slcli command you will be able to retrieve all the datacenters "keyName" available for this package "VIRTUAL_ROUTER_APPLIANCE_1_GPBS
":  slcli order package-locations VIRTUAL_ROUTER_APPLIANCE_1_GPBS

Comment: if you want to get the keynames then you need to look for datacenter regions, https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Location_Datacenter/#regions, and to retrieve that values you need to use the object-mask feature, try with `https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Location_Datacenter/getDatacenters?objectMask=mask[regions]`